# Migration Issue With ArcGIS 10 in ExportOperationClass

Tags: arcgis-engine

I am migrating my Application built in Version 9.3.1 to version 10
In my code I am getting execption:

```
{"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4147A362-EFC4-11D3-
 A0A4-00C04F6BC626} failed due to the following error: 80040111."}
```

at this place

```
IExportOperation pExportOp = new ExportOperationClass();
```

I have alreday bind my application with bindmanager code

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Engine);
```

Every thing works fine like creating IWorkspaceFactory InitiallizeLicense, exception arise as this statment is executed.

```
IExportOperation pExportOp = new ExportOperationClass();
```

I found at google that beside binding , some times we have to use

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.VersionManager.LoadVersion(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Engine, "10.0");
```

but I am not able to access ESRI.ArcGIS.VersionManager

Is there any solution to avoid exception?